# Android Studio ¿Como logro un scroll view que afecte a un recycler view y además desplaze vistas?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Descripción de la imágen:**

Esta imágen muestra una actividad tabbeada. El **View Pager** se encarga de cambiar los fragments según la tab seleccionada. Cada uno de estos **Fragments** contiene un **recycler view**.

**Descripción del problema:**

Me gustaría poder poner un Scroll View dentro de la **actividad tabbeada** el cual "bloquee" (por decirlo de alguna manera) el scroll del **Recycler View** (que no se pueda deslizar por este) hasta cierto punto:

Quiero que se logre descender hasta un punto en el que la **Tab Layout** quede **JUSTO POR DEBAJO** del primer **TXT (Mi nombre)** y, llegados a este punto, se "desbloquee" (por decirlo de alguna manera) el scroll del recycler.

**Datos EXTRA:**

**Este efecto es EXACTAMENTE el mismo que el que tiene Instagram en los perfiles. Podrán notar que al ir descendiendo para ver las fotos de un perfil, el tab layout que divide las fotos va ascendiendo, tapando las vistas de arriba. Una vez que llega arriba de todo, recién ahí se puede deslizar el recycler**

Gracias por leer y espero poder resolver esto!

Comment: Eso lo puedes hacer usando CoordinatorLayout. Su función es exactamente eso, coordinar movimientos entre vistas.  Te dejo un tutorial: https://blog.mindorks.com/using-coordinator-layout-in-android

Comment: Muchas gracias. Voy a investigarlo!